# Extraction of usernames from the text file in a script

Tags: linux, unix, if-statement, scripting, do-while

I am a newbie to linux scripting and I am getting an unexpected error. I have made a script which takes into account two options 1 and 2. I am having issues with option 2 I want to extract the usernames from a text file and add all of the users except the EOF to the home directory like this:

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, why do you want a wacky input format like that? Just one user per line, no comments, no explicit EOF would make things a lot easier, to the point where this can be reduced to a one-linet.

Comment: `if (test whatever)` needlessly creates a subshell (that's what parentheses do) but saves you from needing a space after *whatever*. That's false economy; you want `if [ whatever ]` with spaces inside the square beackets, or just `if test whatever` (remember that `[` is basically a synonym for `test`). Similarly in the `while` condition, you need spaces between all the tokens.

Comment: You need double quotes around all your variable interpolations. `test $num = 2` will evaluate to `test = 2` (a syntax error) if `num` is empty. Quoting `"$num"` fixes that. Similarly for other variables.

Comment: Having the script accept an optional file name argument instead would do away with the pesky interactive prompting, and be easier to use as well (because you get tab completion, command history etc from the shell). But then, the whole script could be replaced with just `xargs -a "$file" -n 1 useradd` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for parsing your input file:

```
if [ -e $Path ]
then
    while read user
    do
        [[ $user = \#* ]] && continue
        Username=`echo $user | cut -f2 -d:`
        if [ "$Username" != "EOF" ]
        then
            echo $Username
        fi
    done < $Path
fi
```